# Socket-Io: Client side 'connect' event not firing when socket is already setup

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, listener

I set up a websocket with socketio in the browser console such that

```
socket.socket.connected
```

returns true. But if I then add:

```
socket.on('connect', function () {console.log('some'); });
```

nothing happens i.e. 'some' is not logged. This is from the official socket-io page:

```
var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('connect', function () { 
    socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', function (data) {
      console.log(data); 
    });
  });
```

I suppose this code is working. But I'm now suspecting that it only works because when the listener is setup (i.e. `socket.on...`) the socket is not connected and only because of the delay for setting up the connection the listener is active when the connection is established. If that would be correct than this would mean that if I got a client with an unreasonable high load after io.connect() is called such that the connection is established before the listener is setup I'm running into trouble because the listener never fires.

- Is this correct?
- How can I setup a listener that fires in both cases:

  1. The connection is not yet established when the listener is setup
  2. The connection is already established when the listener is setup

Thank you and best regards

Comment: I have the same problem now, did you resolve the issue?

Comment: I posted my current solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
callBackOnConnect: function(socket, callback) {
    if (socket.socket.connected) {
        callback();
    } else {
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            callback();
        });
    }
}
```

AFAIK this is safe - though not pretty for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't find it in the documentation, I ran some tests that put a lot of strain on the client after io.connect() was called.  In all cases, the client's 'connect' event fired well after the last listener had been set up.  For example: (thanks to [www.sean.co.uk](http://www.sean.co.uk/a/webdesign/javascriptdelay.shtm) for the JavaScript delay)

```
var socket = io.connect();

// www.sean.co.uk
function pausecomp(millis)
{
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;

    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < millis);
}

//keeps processing for 5 seconds to simulate
//any CPU-intensive process
pausecomp(5000);

//listener gets set up after delay
socket.on('connect', function() {
    //the time that the connect event is fired is compared
    //with the listener's set up time
    console.log(new Date().getTime() - setUpTime);
});

//the time that the listeners are set up is logged
var setUpTime = new Date().getTime();
```

Every time I ran this, I logged a positive result (rather than not getting a result at all).  Interestingly, the higher the pause, the longer after setup it took for 'connect' to fire.  I know that's not proof, but it's at least suggestive.

Regarding when the listeners should be set up, as long as they come after io.connect() and they aren't inside callbacks, they'll be set up before the server fires the 'connection' event, which as far as I can tell comes before the client's 'connect' event.  I would be grateful if someone could point me in the direction of a resource that gets into detail about how and when these built-in events are called, but as far as I can tell they just work without worrying about these things.